# document.write with CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, document.write

I know I am probably doing this wrong because if trying this through [try coffeescript feature](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) it works but surprisingly it doesn't emit any result on my example:

```
<!--http://f.cl.ly/items/1u3Q3W101U2T18162v0V/test.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/coffeescript" >
    document.write "<h2>TEST</h2>"
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `document.write` method doesn't seems to output anything to the body, in this case console.log works fine but not `document.write`

Even after trying to run the script with a `onload` handler like I use in javascript

```
var loaded = function(){
  alert("hello");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded);
```

but then in coffeescript as

```
loaded = ->
   alert "hello"

document.addEventListener "DOMContentLoaded", loaded
```

it seems neither the event method is being fired as opposed to javascript version

Anyone could help me find out what is happening?

Thanks

---

## UPDATE

if running the console after the page is loaded I can get the following to work without problem:

```
CoffeeScript.eval('document.write "<h1>testing</h1>"')
```

but still wondering why the page itself is not showing automatically

### Works on Firefox and Chrome but not in Safari

It seems the page is not showing if using Safari `5.0.3`

Comment: sorry about my bogus answer, @ludicco  - I guess I am a little slow today :-)

Comment: @kjy112 really? that's weird...I am really confused :/

Comment: wow, that's odd, well I've just uploaded the code above to the cloud its running at http://f.cl.ly/items/1u3Q3W101U2T18162v0V/test.html so I guess it should run ok for you guys as well right? could you confirm if this urls also displays the TEST header on screen please?

Comment: thanks guys, I've just noticed it works on Firefox but not in Safari `5.0.3` for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a humdinger, but after investigating, I've got your answer:

The way `coffee-script.js` works is that it looks for, and runs, scripts with `type="text/coffeescript"` after the document has loaded. In the case of Safari, that means that

```
<script type="text/coffeescript">
  document.write "<h2>TEST</h2>"
</script>
```

is equivalent to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.write("<h2>TEST</h2>");
  }, false);
</script>
```

which silently fails. Note that making the insertion with the `document.createElement` method described by Erlend, or with a library like jQuery, will work fine.

Since this works in Chrome, I'd go ahead and call it a Safari bug. But the real moral of the story is: **Don't use document.write.**

Comment: Trevor thanks a lot for your explanation, its good to know what was happening there. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anything about CoffeeScript, but **don't use document.write**. It is evil: http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Use createElement and appendChild/insertBefore instead:

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = "Lolz";
document.body.appendChild(p);

myDiv = document.getElementById("aDiv");
document.body.insertBefore(p, myDiv);
```

document.write has problems in Safari as well.